# Automatically save Tensorboard-like plot of loss to image file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am currently trying to predict the movement of a particle using a tensorflow premade Estimator (tf.estimator.DNNRegressor).

I want to save an image of the average loss plot, like the one tensorboard displays, into each model's folder.[image: Image from tensorboard]

Tensorboard is pretty good to monitor this during training, but I want to save an image for future reference (e.g. comparing different approaches visually)

Is there an easy way to do this?
I could save the results of the evaluation at different times and use matplotlib, but I haven't found anything on how to get the loss from the regressor.train method.

Comment: Not actual solutions, but alternatives. 1) You can download the data in JSON/CSV (check "Show data download links" in upper-left corner) and plot it with Excel/Pandas/etc. 2) Someone wrote [exportTensorFlowLog](https://github.com/anderskm/exportTensorFlowLog) to solve this problem (didn't test it myself) 3) Browser developer tools let you to take screenshots of specific elements (e.g. [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#node-screenshots), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Taking_screenshots#Taking_a_screenshot_of_an_element))

Comment: exportTensorFlowLog works well for me - I'd recommend it

Answer (score 10):

Yes, currently, you can download the `.svg` of loss/other_metric history as [@Jdehesa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079373/automatically-save-tensorboard-like-plot-of-loss-to-image-file/61987395#comment89148328_51079373) pointed out in the comment:

1. Check `Show data download links`;
2. You can see a download symbol on the bottom of the figure;
3. See the yellow marks in the figure if you can't locate them.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to do it programmatically, you could combine the CSVLogger and a custom callback for plotting:

```
class CustomCallbackPlot(Callback):

def __init__(self, training_data_dir):
    self.tdr = training_data_dir

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    df_loan = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(self.tdr, 'training_metrics.csv'))
    df_loan[['loss', 'val_loss']].plot()
    plt.xlabel('epochs')
    plt.title('train/val loss')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(self.tdr, 'training_metrics.png'))
```

use the CSVLogger callback to first generate the training and validation loss data. After that use this CustomCallbackPlot to plot it.

```
    csv_logger = CSVLogger(os.path.join(self.training_data_dir, 'training_metrics.csv'))
    callbacks = [csv_logger, CustomCallbackPlot(self.training_data_dir)]
```

in my example I use the `training_data_dir` to store the path.